# How many peoples did ibn taymiyyah takired(excommunicated)?

Tags: ibn-taymiyyah

Ibn taymiyyah and other scholars takired(excommunicated) ibn sina

> For this reason, scholars such as al-Ghazali, Ibn Taymiyya, and Ibn al-Qayyim considered Ibn Sina to be a disbeliever.[*Source*](https://seekersguidance.org/answers/islamic-belief/ibn-sina-muslim/)

I want to know how many people did he takired other than ibn sina .